# Implementing Google Directions in MapFragment using JSON and Google Maps Android API v2

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-mobile

Can anyone help me implement Google Directions in a MapFragment using JSON and Google Maps Android API v2? I found this one here:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11745314](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11745314/why-retrieving-google-directions-for-android-using-kml-data-is-not-working-anymo/11745316#11745316)

But, it is using MapView. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a great implementation of road direction from the following links:

[Is there a way to show road directions in Google Map API v2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14554078/is-there-a-way-to-show-road-directions-in-google-map-api-v2)

[Get driving directions using Google Maps API v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14495030/google-map-api-v2-get-driving-directions/15053901#15053901)

and check this post as well.

[GoogleMaps v2 route in real time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14873491/googlemaps-v2-route-in-real-time/15178637#15178637)