# How to display route between two coordinates on mapView

Tags: java, android, dictionary, draw, routes

I apologizes if this is a repeated question but i had hard time trying to display route between two places (from current location to desire location). I was trying this using one of the google api.

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=40.193251,-76.731619&destination=54.470038,-2.636719&sensor=true&mode=driving
```

But this is not consistant. This works sometimes but sometimes not. Apart from this it doesn't show long route like from India to USA.

Can anybody suggest what i should go through. If anybody have good experience in displaying route between two places in android. please share code or any which working perfectly and consistently. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the issue and used google KML to draw the route, Here is the link to 
[KML resources.](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/mapsSupport#googlemapsformobile) and overlay the points on map as in [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5608601/android-google-maps-and-drawing-route)